# PyCharm can't find import in same folder

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

I'm using PyCharm and I'm importing some constants from another python file in the same directory. The import works at runtime, but I get this annoying red underline on the import statement and also every time I use a constant from the file.

Here's the file hierarchy

[image]

**(Please ignore the red underlining on the folders, they are unrelated to this)**

What causes this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Comment: The same thing happens for me when I'm editing a file inside a subdirectory of a project. This doesn't cause issues when running, say, `pca_mixtures/funcs.py` directly, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is better if you replace that with:

```
from pca_mixtures.constants import *
```

The issue is because of how PyCharm sets PYTHONPATH to the root of your project.

While you can add directories as `Sources`, I would not recommended. That will make your project fragile.

Comment: first, it didn't help me as the error still shows, second - i don't think its best practice since your project might have colliding constants one day (like we did ) when you import everything you have no control.

Answer (score 13):

You can right click `pca_mixtures` and then mark the directory as **Sources Root**, this should solve your problem. Good luck!

Comment: Can one have multiple source roots?

Comment: If you mean to set multiple sub-directories in a directory as sources root, the answer is yes, it's possible.

Comment: Here you can also find another confirmation of proper solution for your issue: (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203465584/comments/360000116800)

Comment: Thank you, fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `from .constants import *`. 
Always check if you're able to `control+click/ cmd+click`  to your imported file

Comment: I tried this before and it gives an `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` message.