# Import fails in terminal but works in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm for a project with the following file hierarchy:

[image]

And I'm running main.py in PyCharm with the following configurations:

Working Directory: `/Users/me/longpath/project/amlproject/pca_mixtures`.

When I try to run in terminal, it fails:

```
~/longpath/project/amlproject/pca_mixtures$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pca_mixtures.funcs import PCAMixture
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pca_mixtures'
```

and nothing changes if I jump up to the parent folder:

```
~/longpath/project/amlproject$ python pca_mixtures/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pca_mixtures/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pca_mixtures.funcs import PCAMixture
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pca_mixtures'
```

The reason for using `from pca_mixtures.funcs import PCAMixture` instead of just `from funcs import PCAMixture` was so that PyCharm would recognize the import and not red-underline it, as I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091811/pycharm-cant-find-import-in-same-folder/54091923). Now, it seems that this has lead to me not being able to run the project in the terminal.

How would you handle this? I want to be able to run it in the terminal because the PyCharm output is not fully sequential (error messages output before program output) which is annoying when debugging.

Comment: Apparently, PyCharm sets your PYTHONPATH to include `~/longpath/project/amlproject/`, and thus it is able to find `pca_mixtures`. On the command line in your terminal, this doesn't happen by itself. You'd have to set PYTHONPATH to include that (parent) directory.

Comment: Alternatively, consider using a relative import in `main.py`: `from .funcs import PCAMixture` should work.

Comment: Note that you have made `pca_mixtures` a package (with `__init__.py` in that directory); you should probably not run `main.py` like that if it lives in the same package, but move it out of the package in the first place.

Comment: Went with your last option cause it made most sense to me. Thanks!